# spring security hasAuthority("SCOPE_xxx") method not working with spring authorization server version 0.2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I have created an authorization server using the new spring authorization server module. I am able to get the token successfully but when I try to use the token against a protected endpoint with `hasAuthority()` I get forbidden 403 error. Below my `pom.xml` file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.erycoking</groupId>
    <artifactId>auth-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>auth-service</name>
    <description>Auth Service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <jhipster-dependencies.version>7.0.1</jhipster-dependencies.version>
        <liquibase.version>4.6.1</liquibase.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.jhipster</groupId>
            <artifactId>jhipster-framework</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jackson Configurations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hibernate5</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-hppc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>problem-spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>0.26.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <!-- Inherited version from Spring Boot can't be used because of regressions -->
            <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liquibase.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Below is my Authorization Server config

```
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
public class AuthServerConfig {

    private final DataSource dataSource;
    private final AuthProperties authProps;
    private final TokenSettings tokenSettings;

    public AuthServerConfig(DataSource dataSource, AuthProperties authProps, TokenSettings tokenSettings) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
        this.authProps = authProps;
        this.tokenSettings = tokenSettings;
    }

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
    public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        JdbcRegisteredClientRepository clientRepository = new JdbcRegisteredClientRepository(jdbcTemplate);
        clientRepository.save(webClient());
        return clientRepository;
    }

    private RegisteredClient webClient() {
        return RegisteredClient.withId("98a9104c-a9c7-4d7c-ad03-ec61bcfeab36")
                .clientId(authProps.getClientId())
                .clientName(authProps.getClientName())
                .clientSecret(authProps.getClientSecret())
                .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS)
                .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                .scope("create").scope("read").scope("write").scope("update").scope("delete")
                .tokenSettings(tokenSettings)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationService authorizationService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,
                                                           RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2AuthorizationConsentService authorizationConsentService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate,
                                                                         RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository) {
        return new JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationConsentService(jdbcTemplate, registeredClientRepository);
    }

    @Bean
    public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
        RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
        JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
        return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
    }

    private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
        KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
        return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                .privateKey(privateKey)
                .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .build();
    }

    private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
        KeyPair keyPair;
        try {
            KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
            keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
        }
        return keyPair;
    }

    @Bean
    public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
        return ProviderSettings.builder()
                .issuer(authProps.getIssuerUri())
                .build();
    }

}
```

And this is my Security Config

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/management/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                    //this does not work
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/user").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
                    //this does not work
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/auth/user").hasAuthority("SCOPE_read")
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable()
                .and()
                .formLogin(withDefaults())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder delegatingPasswordEncoder() {
        Map<String, PasswordEncoder> encoders = new HashMap<>();
        encoders.put("bcrypt", new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        DelegatingPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new DelegatingPasswordEncoder("bcrypt", encoders);
        passwordEncoder.setDefaultPasswordEncoderForMatches(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return passwordEncoder;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenSettings tokenSettings() {
        return TokenSettings.builder()
                .accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
                .refreshTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofHours(24))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Here is my user detail service

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return userRepository.findOneWithRolesByEmailIgnoreCase(login)
                .map(user -> createSpringSecurityUser(login, user))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
    }

    private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {
        if (!user.isActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        user.getRoles().forEach(e -> {
            grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(e.getName()));
            e.getPermissions().forEach(p -> grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(p.getName())));
        });
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), grantedAuthorities);
    }
}
```

when using the token to make a request to an endpoint that requires authentication alone it succeeds but when I try using it on an endpoint that requires a role it fails.

What could be the issue?

Comment: I believe the issue could be related to your UserDetailsService not provided here. You are expecting your UserDetailsService to provide scopes when you log in using username/password. Perhaps you're blending a resource server with your authorization server, when they should be two separate applications.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I have edited the question and added the userDetailService

Comment: What do the roles look like in the database? If they are not `SCOPE_read` that is why a request like `GET /auth/user` will fail.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg the `SCOPE_read` is a client scope, not a user role/authority that is why it is prefixed with `SCOPE_` hence it will validate if the client has a read scope, which is true coz of this line `.scope("create").scope("read").scope("write").scope("update").scope("delete")` in the Authorization server config. As long as the client has this scope then the request should go through

Comment: Unfortunately not, based on how you have your filter chain configured. You are authenticating with form login, which uses roles. The authorization server configuration is for your OAuth client, not for the user within the context of the authorization server itself.

Comment: @SteveRiesenberg I beg to differ, but just so we are on the same page kindly explain further and how you would have implemented it. kindly...

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and also for clearing the confusion I had. Thank you for taking the time to answer me. @SteveRiesenberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on a brief discussion in comments to clarify your setup, it seems that you are configuring your authorization server as a regular secured application with the intention of using scopes as authorities. However, this is an incorrect usage of the authorization server.

Note: I have not seen any reference to an OAuth 2.0 client or resource server in your description, so I'm assuming you are trying to hit endpoints directly on the authorization server. If that's not the case, let me know.

There are three applications involved in an OAuth 2.0 protected setup:

1. Authorization server
2. Resource server
3. Client

Your configuration is only for #1 (as far as I can tell). The authorization server contains two filter chains and additionally a configuration for a single oauth client. The two filter chains do the following:

1. Secure endpoints provided by the authorization server framework
2. Secure the login endpoint(s) the user will interact with prior to using the authorization endpoint (`/oauth2/authorize`) to obtain an authorization code, which the client will later use to obtain an access token

The scopes you have configured would allow a user (resource owner) to grant an oauth client the ability to make a protected call to a resource server using an access token. Only when the client makes a call to a resource server will your configured scopes be used. When the user directly interacts with an endpoint on the authorization server using a browser, the configuration for form login is in play, which as I mentioned in comments, uses roles from your database.

See the [SpringOne 2021 repository](https://github.com/sjohnr/springone-2021) and [presentation](https://github.com/sjohnr/springone-2021) to understand how to take an application from an unsecured application to a secured one, and then see how we turn it into a resource server, which uses scopes as authorities.

The presentation demonstrates all three applications, though the focus is on the resource server, which matches closely what you are trying to accomplish with scopes as authorities.